# css - jquery mobile style not applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to learn: "**jquery mobile + ajax + php + css**" and I'm right now working on the registration-system of my mobile web page.

In my `login.php` I've built-in a submit button which gives out a message with

> "Username is missing" or "Password is wrong"

If one out of the two textboxes is empty one of those messages pops up.

If both textboxes are filled with any values a message is displayed that the login has been successfully done when you submit.

The background of the displayed messages `(showSuccess(), showError())` are filled with colors but the problem is that one of those colors are not working.

login.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Webapplication</title>
<link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

</head> 
<body> 

<div id="page" data-role="page">
    <div id="header" data-role="header">
        <h1>TEST- Login Page</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="content" data-role="content">
    <form>
        <div =id="loginForm">   
        <h2>Enter your credentials to login</h2>
        <div id="usernameDiv" data-role="field-contain">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"/>
        </div><!-- end usernameDIV -->

        <div id="passwordDiv" data-role="field-contain">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" id="password">
        </div><!-- end usernameDIV -->

        <div id="loginButtonDiv" data-role="field-contain">
        <button name="login" type="submit" data-theme="a" data-mini="true" data-inline="true">Login</button>
        </div>
</div>  
</form>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>TEST</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Seite zwei</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Inhalt      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Fußzeile</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page3">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Seite drei</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Inhalt      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Fußzeile</h4>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="page4">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Seite vier</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">   
        Inhalt      
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Fußzeile</h4>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

login.js

```
$(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(){

        if(validateUsername() && validateUserPassword())
        {
            showSuccess('You have logged in successfully');

        }


        function validateUsername()
        {   
            if($('#username').val().length == 0)
            {
                showError('Username failed');

            return false;
            }

            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        function validateUserPassword()
        {
            if($('#password').val().length == 0)
            {
                showError('Password failed');

            return false;
            }

            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

function showError(message){
//show error message
    $( "<div class='ui_body_error ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all'><h1>"+message+"</h1></div>" )
    .css({"display": "block", "opacity": 0.96, "top": $(window).scrollTop() + 100 })
    .appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
    .delay( 1000 )
    .fadeOut( 600, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
    });
}

function showSuccess(message){
//show success message
    $( "<div class='ui_body_success ui-loader ui-overlay-shadow ui-corner-all'><h1>"+message+"</h1></div>" )
    .css({"display": "block", "opacity": 0.96, "top": $(window).scrollTop() + 100 })
    .appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer )
    .delay( 1000 )
    .fadeOut( 600, function() {
    $( this ).remove();
    });
}

        return false;
    })
})
```

custom.css

```
.ui_body_success
{
    border:1px solid #24AF11;
    color:#333;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    background:#89f07C;
    background-image:-webkit--gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#89F07C);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#00DF55);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
}


.ui_body_error
{
    border:1px solid #F7503A;
    color:#333;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    background:#FBB99E;
    background-image:-webkit--gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#FBB99E);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
}
```

The style **.ui_body_success** is working fine and when I exchange the positions of ".ui_body_success" and ".ui_body_error". On that way the first one is almost working.

```
.ui_body_error
{
    border:1px solid #F7503A;
    color:#333;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    background:#FBB99E;
    background-image:-webkit--gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#FBB99E);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
    background-image:-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#FBB99E);
}

.ui_body_success
{
    border:1px solid #24AF11;
    color:#333;text-shadow:0 1px 0 #fff;
    background:#89f07C;
    background-image:-webkit--gradient(linear,left top,left bottom,from(#fff),to(#89F07C);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#00DF55);
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-ms-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
    background-image:-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#89f07C);
}
```

I can't find a solution

Comment: In showSuccess() you have return false, in showError you don't have it. Also what does "almost working" mean? Theoretically the order shouldn't change anything in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In showSuccess() you have return false, in showError you don't have it